# How can I execute a simulink diagram running in external mode from a Matlab script?

Tags: matlab, batch-file, simulink

**Matlab** provides the *sim* command that can be used in a **Matlab** script to call and execute a **Simulink** model. But the function seems to be restricted to models that only run in *Normal* mode. When I try to call a **Simulink** model that runs in *External* mode, **Matlab** halts the script and flags it as an error. Besides being a nuisance it seems to me an unnecessary restriction on what could be a very useful application.

In any event is there a work around, perhaps a different command that I can use to run the **Simulink** diagram in *External* mode from the **Matlab** script?

I did try using the **Matlab** DOS shell command (using !) but it requires opening another instance of **Matlab**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

External Mode doesn't run a simulation, rather it is a mechanism for using the Simulink model's front end as a way of changing and viewing data that is running elsewhere (e.g. an executable running on the same machine as the model, or code running on an external processor).

To do that from the command line (or within code) you need to use a combination of the following commands:

```
>> set_param(gcs,'SimulationMode','external') % put model into External Mode
>> set_param(gcs,'SimulationCommand','connect') % connect to the executable
>> set_param(gcs,'SimulationCommand','start') % Start the executable
>> set_param(gcs,'SimulationCommand','stop')  % Stop the executable
```

Comment: Thanks - that answer is indeed correct as I eventually discovered on my own. In my case the external computer is another PC running XPC target. And the m-file script I wrote to automate a process and collect data essentially uses the sequence you suggested.